# FlutterWebApp trouble local host

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I have a flutter web app already compiled, I have it local because my DB is also local, when I have an internet connection the web works perfectly, but when I do not have internet does not load, some tips

Do I have to modify something in the code?

Comment: Hello @devCArls it will be difficult for anyone to help without more details, such as showing the relevant code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.